# How to select rows that are like other rows in the same table & column

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to find rows that contain the "&" character and are like the rows with the "&" character but do not contain any characters after and including the "&" character from the examples below. Both rows would be selected from the same item column in the items table. I would like both the rows with the "&" and the rows without the "&" returned. If no rows exist for the item without the "&", I still would like the row returned as blank or null.

What I have below currently selects the items with the "&" and selects the characters after and including the "&" character, but I need help figuring out how to find the rows that do not have the "&" character or characters after the "&" based on the data currently selected. This query is being run in Oracle.

| item |
| --- |
| abc&123 |
| def&456 |
| xyz&789 |
| 123456 |
| 123457 |

---

```
select item, substr(item, instr(item, '&')) as Trimmed_Item 
from items where item like '%&%';
```

Current result:

| item | Trimmed_Item |
| --- | --- |
| abc&123 | &123 |
| def&456 | &456 |
| xyz&789 | &789 |

Desired result:

| item | Trimmed_Item |
| --- | --- |
| abc&123 | abc |
| def&456 | def |
| xyz&789 |  |

Does anybody have an idea of how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not Oracle expert, but I believe `strtok()` exists (Correct me if I'm wrong). `SELECT item, strtok(item, '&', 1) as Trimmed_Item FROM items;` should do the job.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm receiving an invalid identifier error for strtok(). Doesn't look like I can use that function.

Comment: That's a bummer.

Comment: use substr(item, 1, instr(item, '&')-1) and add a where clause item like '%&%'. Will be an inefficient query if the number of rows is exploding. In that case change your design. Do the processing while inserting the data.

Comment: Adding the where clause gives me all rows with an "&" but does not return the other set of data I'm looking for where the row is like the "&" item without the "&" character and characters after. I'll update my query above, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
with items as 
     (
       select 'abc'||chr(38)||'123' as item from dual union all
       select 'def'||chr(38)||'456' as item from dual union all
       select 'xyz'||chr(38)||'789' as item from dual union all
       select '123456'              as item from dual union all
       select '123457'              as item from dual
     )
    select item, decode(regexp_substr(item, '[^&]+', 1, 1),item,' ',regexp_substr(item, '[^&]+', 1, 1)) as Trimmed_Item
      from items

ITEM    TRIMMED_ITEM
------- -------------
abc&123 abc    
def&456 def    
xyz&789 xyz    
123456         
123457
```

Thank you